# Scale node.js socket.io with 3 servers

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io

I know their are a lot of questions and answers about this issue on the net but I can't get it to work.

I have a server written in `node.js` and listening to connections with `socket.io`

Now, The sockets can exchange messages between them, like a chat and I'm broadcasting the incoming messages to all other sockets on the server.

I want to run my `node` server on 3 different servers, each one of them have different IP, Lets call them: `SERVER1`, `SERVER2` and `SERVER3`.
Here comes my confusion, if i'm sending a message from a socket which connected to `SERVER1`, How the sockets that connected to `SERVER2` and `SERVER3` will see this message?

I heard about `RedisStore`, `RabbitMQ` and other stuff but i can't find a good article/post/book that can explain me how to do it right...

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe RedisStore does this automatically for you, here's a good post about it: http://www.ranu.com.ar/2011/11/redisstore-and-rooms-with-socketio.html

How is this done internally?

Well as you have heard, Redis, RabbitMQ, ZeroMQ etc have pub-sub functionality, meaning you can subscribe to channels and publish info on them (to all the connected peers):

https://github.com/mranney/node_redis#publish--subscribe

So server A, B and C are subscribed to the same channel. When a client connected to server A wants to send a message for all the users connected to the chat room "js" for example, he sends a message to the server A and server A publishes a message on the "js" channel.
All the rest of the servers get that message and broadcast it to all their clients.

Comment: So, you mean that one of my servers should run only a `redis` server and my other two servers will run my `node/socket.io` server code and subscribe all income messages to the `redis` server?

Comment: Yes that's the idea, but every connected peer should both publish and subscribe to Redis.